# Excel intenta conectarse a un archivo en línea desconocido

Tags: excel

Muy buenas!

Resulta que en el trabajo tengo un documento excel que me han cedido con el que tengo trabajar. La cuestión es que cada vez que abro el archivo **intenta conectarse con un servidor** desconocido para mi, es decir, actualmente al menos no se requiere para nada en el funcionamiento del excel, puede que antes, pero ya no...

> El mensaje que me salta es el siguiente:
>
> Microsft Excel no puede obtener acceso al archivo "https:/......."
> Puede haber varios motivos:
> -El nombre o la ruta del archivo no existen
> -Otro programa está usando el archivo
> -EL libro que está intentando guardar tiene el mismo nombre que otro libreo que está abierto en estos momentos.

-He consultado VBA, no tiene ninguna macro
-He consultado los hipervínculos, y si que tiene, pero son otros archivos que están en local, eso es normal.
-He consultado "Conexiones Existentes" en Datos>Obtener y Transformar datos, y tampoco aparece nada linkeado.

Alguna idea? Ya no se donde mirar, cada vez que abro el libro se pone a comprobar y se tira unos cuantos minutos en ello hasta que da el error.

Comment: ¿Este Excel tiene alguna tabla dinámica?

Comment: en VBA miraste solo los módulos o también las hojas, formularios y libros? Podría ser también una fórmula que esté intentando conectarse a ese sitio

Comment: Buenos días chicos, lo primero, gracias por responder, os comento. @RogerTorné El excel no cuenta con ninguna tabla dinámica.

Comment: También mire las hojas y los formularios , ya que no tiene módulos, en este caso no tiene nada en VBA. Es unicamente una hoja, con una tabla donde cada celda esta enlazada a un archivo en local mediante la ruta "C:/Users/......" . He probado moviendo los libros de ubicación para comprobar que el fallo no sea de unos de los libros que intenta abrir, y no es el caso, estoy bastante perdido y  quemado @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Comment: Si no necesitas ese archivo al que se conecta, coge todas las celdas enlazadas y conviértelo en valores todo.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Buenas Elier, no he podido responder antes, que me surgieron otras urgencias. Me hacen falta esos enlaces a esos archivos, aunque si que es verdad que esos archivos estan en la carpeta de un Sharepoint, pero esta sincronizado el Sharepoint en local, no debería de generar ningun problema, no?...